# MVC Interdependent controllers : Who gets to store?

Tags: qt, design-patterns, model-view-controller

With a friend of mine we are having an argument about the MVC (Model View Controller) Design Pattern. We are working on a project where two of our controllers are interdependent :

We are manipulating two types of objects : **Pattern and Layout**. A Layout is a composition of Patterns, which means that in the Model, a Layout has a std::vector of Patterns. Actually, when we want to create a Pattern, we must have created a Layout before because a Pattern cannot exists without being in a Layout.

Knowing that, we want to implement the Controllers for these two types of data and **are arguing about who gets to store the Pattern datas**.

From my friend point of view, **as the Pattern cannot exists without a Layout we can let the Layout Controller the charge of storing** the Pattern datas in the Layout Model.

From my point of view, as we are talking about Pattern data, I would prefer to l**et the Pattern Controller handle everything Pattern related**. So the Pattern Controller would have a container of Patterns and the Layout Controller a list of pointers to the Patterns present in the Layout.

The advantage of my friend's technique is that we do not have the data in two places (Pattern Controller Container and Layout Data) and the advantage of mine is that the roles of each controllers are not mixed and that we can manipulate a Pattern without knowing what Layout it belongs to. What do you think ?

Comment: I think this kind of question is better suit on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Yes, sure. I have this fad to consider this so obvious that it doesn't need to be restated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only for storing the Pattern inside the Layout, from my point of view, it is still related to the Layout. The layout knows that he has a list of Pattern. He knows how to store them, how to control the actual vector.

The Pattern should not, from my point of view, be aware that he is in a list above him. That would reduce the coupling. The pattern controller knows how to handle a Pattern. That's it.

So, the LayoutController knows how to work with a Layout, and add Patterns in the list which is located in the Layout

The PatternController knows how to work with a Pattern without knowing where it is stored above him.